# Connection Autodesk Motionbuilder with iOS application using OSC Server

Tags: ios, osc, motionbuilder

I am trying to write a C++ api to connect Autodesk Motionbuilder with iOS application using OSC Server. I am new to API coding with Motionbuilder. 
I am looking for any reference code or any other useful resources.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To stream data into or out of Motionbuilder you would want to use a custom device.  There are samples in your installation directory:

C:\Program Files\Autodesk\MotionBuilder 2016\OpenRealitySDK\samples\devices